# Is it possible to directly connect the kinect to an iphone?

Tags: ios, kinect

Is that possible or do you need to connect the kinect to a computer and stream the images in (almost) real time to an iPhone? Is it even possible to get ~30fps via stream on the iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kinect uses a USB connection and even if you could make up some sort of cable to connect a Kinect to the Lightning or 30 pin connector, iOS would not recognise the Kinect as it does not have a driver, so the short answer is no, you cannot connect a Kinect directly to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution/alternative, you might want to check out [Occipital/Structure.io](http://structure.io/developers), who are selling a depth sensor for (some) iDevices for ca. 380USD.

[Apparently](http://techcrunch.com/2013/09/17/occipitals-new-structure-sensor-turns-your-ipad-into-a-mobile-3d-scanner/) they are using Primesense Carmine sensors ("which is essentially an equivalent of ASUS Xtion Live under different brand name" according to [iPiSoft's sensor comparison] (http://wiki.ipisoft.com/Depth_Sensors_Comparison)). 
You can review the differences to the Kinect at the previous link, but basically it boils down to the Kinect being bigger and heavier, having a motorized tilt and requiring external power.

To get back to your question:

if you look around you'll find working examples of how to get OpenNI running on BeagleBone dev-boards under Linux, and thus it is more than conceivable that you'll be able to compile and run it for/on iOS as well (possibly requiring a jailbreak).

You could also have a look at [libfreenect](https://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started), another open implementation of drivers for the Primesense family of sensors (as well as the Kinect 2).